# Error Send Email : An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, email

I am trying to create a sending email app and found some error. the email will be send to a certain recipient using checkbox inside gridview.
the condition are:

> if email in coulmn 16 is not null then the email will be send directly. --> this is already work
>
> if email in column 16 is null then the email will be send to the recipient in column 17. --> it's throw an error in this part.

here is my code for sending the mail:

```
Dim X As Integer
    For X = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(18).Controls(1), CheckBox)
        If chkBox.Checked = True Then
Dim email2 As String
            If GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(16).Text <> "" Then
                email2 = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(16).Text)
            Else
                email2 = Trim(GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(17).Text)
            End If
            Try
                Dim EmailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
                EmailMessage.From = New MailAddress("mailaddress.bla.com")
                EmailMessage.To.Add(email2)
                EmailMessage.Subject = "Attire Request"
                EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
                Dim link As String = "some link"
                EmailMessage.Body = "Please login by Using this link <a href=""" & link & """>Click here </a>"

                Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(Server2)
                Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username2, Password2)
                smtp.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
                smtp.Send(EmailMessage)

            Catch ex As Exception
                ' lblError.Text = lblError.Text & ex.Message & " " & ex.InnerException.ToString
                lblError.Text = ex.Message
                lblError.Visible = True
            End Try
```

it's throws an error : An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'.
do you have any suggestion how to fix this.
edited : code for looping

Thanks in advances.

Comment: while debugging what is the value of `email2`?

Comment: i think it occurs due to the input error in the `GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(17).Text` check the field value for confirmation.

Comment: @PawanS it display dim email as string...

Comment: @SujithKarivelil it's works fine when I send it directly to recipient in column 17.

Comment: then what is the problem

Comment: No, it should show proper email id. See your grid 17, I feel it is returning wrong email address

Comment: @SujithKarivelil I want to apply the condition if coulmn 16 is null then send to column 17.... it's only work when I sent it directly without that condition...

Comment: @PawanS it display blablabla gridview1 control... there no a proper email id displayed when I run it and see the grid 17.

Comment: see the answer, hope that it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your if-else statement as follows:

```
If GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(16).Value.ToString <> "" Then
email2 = Trim(GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(16).Value.ToString)
Else
email2 = Trim(GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(17).Value.ToString)
End If
```

Note:- the Row is selected on the basics of the value of X; loop can be used to select multiple rows in single click

[image: Screen shot of my execution of the above code]

Comment: you are using C# or vb.net? it is the code for vb.net

Comment: see the scree shot which explains my execution, hope that now my answer is acceptable for you

Comment: why it shows an error on my code.... I copy your code to make sure I am not typo but it show an error...

Comment: may be the version of VS you are using: i am working with VS2010

Comment: I have solved it... I use null variable to stored the email... Thanks for the help Sujith... I really appreciate it..